# Problema al mostrar dos imágenes dentro de una celda en la tabla HTML

Tags: html, css

Estoy trabajando con una tabla html que me gustaría en una de sus celdas poder mostrar dos imágenes, el problema que tengo en este momento es que ambas imágenes están juntas por los estilos que se aplican a ellas hasta ahora. entonces como puedo agregar un espacio en el medio de ambos?

```css
.text-content {
  text-align: justify;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 10pt;
}

.text-title {
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 12pt;
  color: #000;
}

.thubnail img {
  float: left;
  max-width: 50%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<table border="1">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <td width="8%">Item</td>
        <td width="8%">Quantity</td>
        <td width="10%">Size</td>
        <td width="50%">Description</td>
        <td width="10%">P/U</td>
        <td width="14%">Total ($.)</td>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td width="8%" rowspan="2" class="text-content">1</td>
        <td width="8%" rowspan="2" class="text-content">3</td>
        <td width="10%" rowspan="2" class="text-content">12 x 6</td>
        <td width="50%" class="text-title">test description</td>
        <td width="10%" rowspan="2" class="text-content">2000</td>
        <td width="14%" rowspan="2" class="text-content">6000</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td rowspan="2" class="text-content">
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing elit dignissim, volutpat sapien tellus cubilia mollis sollicitudin nibh nisi curabitur, nullam semper mi duis erat pellentesque nunc. Quis cursus vulputate auctor habitant quisque nibh facilisi vivamus rutrum cubilia, cras dignissim suspendisse vel condimentum lectus cum mauris integer, aenean luctus augue vitae vestibulum quam ac purus parturient.
          <div class="thubnail">
<img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/77020/desmond.jpg" alt="Desmond">
          </div>
          <div class="thubnail">
<img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/77020/desmond.jpg" alt="Desmond">
          </div>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: ¿Y si pruebas agregando un `margin` de por ejemplo `10px` a la clase `.thubnail`?, pues esta es la que contiene en dos `div` por separado a las etiqueta `img`

Comment: ya intente y la segunda imagen se va para abajo, necesito mantenerlas en linea

Answer (score 2, accepted):

en esta regla.

```
.thubnail img {
  float: left;
  max-width: 50%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Agrégale la propiedad **padding** de esta manera(La cantidad puedes variar).

```
.thubnail img {
  float: left;
  max-width: 50%;
  padding: 1.2em;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Pienso que lo puedes resolver así:

- a la clase `thubnail` quitale el `float` y aplicale un `display: flex;`
- A la etiqueta `img` por separado aplicale un `width` y el `margin` que te comenté por separado para darle en todo su contorno un espacio con respecto de su contenedor padre
- En vez de tener 2 `div` cada uno encerrando una imagen, deja solo uno y dentro de ese coloca las 2 imágenes; *ya que la idea de las `class`* es que puedas aplicar los mismos estilos a diferentes elementos; entonces con un contenedor que englobe a ambas sería mas correcto considero
- A la etiqueta `img` le das un ancho máximo de `90%` para que se ajuste según sea el espacio del `viewport` disponible

Pdiendo tener un resultado así:

```html
    <style>
      .text-content {
      text-align: justify;
      font-weight: bold;
      font-size: 10pt;
    }
    
    .text-title {
      text-align: center;
      font-weight: bold;
      font-size: 12pt;
      color: #000;
    }
    
    .thubnail{
      display: flex;
      max-width: 50%;
      box-sizing: border-box;
    }
      img {
        max-width: 90%;
        margin: 2px;
      }
    </style>
    
    <table border="1">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <td width="8%">Item</td>
            <td width="8%">Quantity</td>
            <td width="10%">Size</td>
            <td width="50%">Description</td>
            <td width="10%">P/U</td>
            <td width="14%">Total ($.)</td>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td width="8%" rowspan="2" class="text-content">1</td>
            <td width="8%" rowspan="2" class="text-content">3</td>
            <td width="10%" rowspan="2" class="text-content">12 x 6</td>
            <td width="50%" class="text-title">test description</td>
            <td width="10%" rowspan="2" class="text-content">2000</td>
            <td width="14%" rowspan="2" class="text-content">6000</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td rowspan="2" class="text-content">
              Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing elit dignissim, volutpat sapien tellus cubilia mollis sollicitudin nibh nisi curabitur, nullam semper mi duis erat pellentesque nunc. Quis cursus vulputate auctor habitant quisque nibh facilisi vivamus rutrum cubilia, cras dignissim suspendisse vel condimentum lectus cum mauris integer, aenean luctus augue vitae vestibulum quam ac purus parturient.
              <div class="thubnail">
    <img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/77020/desmond.jpg" alt="Desmond">
    <img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/77020/desmond.jpg" alt="Desmond">
              </div>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

Answer (score 4):

Una opcion sería la siguiente:

Lo que se agregó fue un `margin`, y al darle, en este caso `2px;` habría que restarle al `max-width` para que la siguiente imagen no baje y se mantenga en la linea.

```css
.text-content {
  text-align: justify;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 10pt;
}

.text-title {
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 12pt;
  color: #000;
}

.thubnail img {
  float: left;
  max-width: 48%;
  margin: 2px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<table border="1">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <td width="8%">Item</td>
        <td width="8%">Quantity</td>
        <td width="10%">Size</td>
        <td width="50%">Description</td>
        <td width="10%">P/U</td>
        <td width="14%">Total ($.)</td>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td width="8%" rowspan="2" class="text-content">1</td>
        <td width="8%" rowspan="2" class="text-content">3</td>
        <td width="10%" rowspan="2" class="text-content">12 x 6</td>
        <td width="50%" class="text-title">test description</td>
        <td width="10%" rowspan="2" class="text-content">2000</td>
        <td width="14%" rowspan="2" class="text-content">6000</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td rowspan="2" class="text-content">
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing elit dignissim, volutpat sapien tellus cubilia mollis sollicitudin nibh nisi curabitur, nullam semper mi duis erat pellentesque nunc. Quis cursus vulputate auctor habitant quisque nibh facilisi vivamus rutrum cubilia, cras dignissim suspendisse vel condimentum lectus cum mauris integer, aenean luctus augue vitae vestibulum quam ac purus parturient.
          <div class="thubnail">
<img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/77020/desmond.jpg" alt="Desmond">
          </div>
          <div class="thubnail">
<img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/77020/desmond.jpg" alt="Desmond">
          </div>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```